# Error inflating checkbox

Tags: android, view, custom-view

I am having weird stack trace from my application in the android market. 
I have a view switcher which contains two views, one of them contains a checkbox.

I am getting this stack trace AdDetailView beeing a custom view.

```
  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckBox
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:382)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
  at com.yakaz.view.AdDetailView.init(AdDetailView.java:67)
  at com.yakaz.view.AdDetailView.<init>(AdDetailView.java:78)
```

This happens in the following view contructor :

```
private void init(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    li.inflate(R.layout.ad_detail_view, this);
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
}

public AdDetailView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}
```

The line 67 is the inflate line.

The problem is that i can't reproduce the problem, on emulator or device. 
Any pointers ?

Here is the ad_detail_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/preview_warning"
    style="@style/Notification" android:text="@string/this_is_only_a_preview"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="none" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:fillViewport="true" android:id="@+id/scrolls">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/action_bar" />

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">
            <!--  tags -->
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tagsLayout"
                android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <CheckBox android:id="@+id/save_button" style="@style/StarButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <!--  meta -->
        <Button android:id="@+id/meta" style="@style/Meta"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>


        <!-- pictures -->
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/gallery_container">
            <Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <!--  padded layout -->
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <!-- summary -->
            <TextView android:id="@+id/summary" style="@style/AdDetailSummary"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <!--  tab -->
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_green_bar" android:paddingLeft="10dp">
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tab_title"
                android:gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/member_profile" style="@style/TabLabel" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- user detail -->
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/very_light_gray" android:paddingBottom="10dp">
            <!--  user item -->

            <include layout="@layout/user_item" />
            <include layout="@layout/website_item" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</merge>
```

style.xml :

```
<style name="StarButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bk_star_button</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:button">@android:id/empty</item>
</style>
```

bk_star_button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_big_off"
      android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_big_on"
      android:state_checked="true"/>          
</selector>
```

here is another layout that as the exact same exception raised on some device :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/bk_gradient">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" style="@style/TopBar"
        android:id="@+id/titlebar">
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp" android:id="@+id/search_progressbar"
        android:visibility="gone">
            <ProgressBar android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            style="@style/ProgressBarMedium" />
        </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttons_container"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
    ....
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

the code that raises the exception :

```
public static CompoundButton addTitleBarCompoundButton(Context context,
        View titleBar, CharSequence label, boolean isChecked) {
    if (!(titleBar instanceof ViewGroup))
        return null;

    ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) titleBar
            .findViewById(R.id.buttons_container);

    // We attach to root during the inflating process othersize layout_
    // parameters in the style are ignored
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.topbar_toggle_button,
            group, true);

    // Get the result, which is the last child of the group
    CompoundButton result = (CompoundButton) group.getChildAt(group
            .getChildCount() - 1);
    result.setChecked(isChecked);

    // Set the text
    result.setText(label);
    return result;
}
```

topbar_toggle_button.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" style="@style/BarButton.Toggle"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it has something to do with you setting the `android:button` parameter to `@android:id/empty`. Can you elaborate on why you are doing this?  It seems to me that you have created custom checked/unchecked views via a `<selector>` on the background, so the button element should be cleared out.  If my assumption is correct, you should do that in this fashion:

```
<style name="StarButton">
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/bk_star_button</item>
  <item name="android:layout_width">30dp</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">30dp</item>
  <item name="android:button">@null</item>
</style>
```

The `@null` attribute is provided as a way to clear default attributes, whereas `@android:id/empty` is the id used by the system to reference the "empty" view that is presented by `AdapterView` instances when they have no items to display.  This discrepancy could cause a host of unknown behaviors.

Comment: i was trying to remove the checkbox icon i'll keep you informed aswell

Comment: this was it, thank you ! sorry for the long time but as i couldn't reproduce the bug i was waiting for no more bug submission on the market, you will get the bounty value asap, as you answered in time :D

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem, try using android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/crime_solved"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="@string/crime_solved_label"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling inflate from the constructor of the `viewroot`, then you should call it with `attachToRoot` parameter `false`:

```
li.inflate(R.layout.ad_detail_view, this);
```

since it is not instantiated yet (you are currently in its constructor).

But based on the error you get, this might not be the only problem, so sharing the xml layout of your `ad_detail_view` might help (the error says the problem is in the xml file, on line #29).

Comment: Added the asked ressources, the line #29 is the CheckBox line. Note that I'm having similar issue on another view switcher with a checkbox too but without any custom view, i can post xml if required.

Comment: might happen, that the `@style/StarButton` style has some inconsistencies?

Comment: added both missing ressources, but on the other side i'm facing same exception with non styled checkbox

Answer (score 1):

It might be (my suggestion) that when you're defining style, you're not giving as parent default CheckBox style. Therefore, in some Android/Device you're missing property that defined in that parent.

Alternatively (as this exception causes problems with CheckBox itself) try to move it to your apk (widget.CheckBox.java).

That's a bad thing that Android Market doesn't allow you to check android version that causes crash. Have you tried to run emulator with Android 1.5 to check this?

Comment: thank you for your answer, i'm desperate on this problem. i'm going to try to define the parent style as checkbox. didn't try on an older emultator but 1.6 install is less than 2% of my user base, and this bug is happening a lot more. i'll keep you informed of the results